# formControlName dentro de componente

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

¿Cómo puedo añadir formControlName dentro de un componente?; he intentado varios acercamientos y no he logrado desacoplar las preguntas en componentes, el cuestionario tienen mas de 400 preguntas

Uno de los errores que se me ha presentado ha sido `Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive`

**Componente Padre**

```
@Component ( {
               selector    : 'app-cuestionario',
               templateUrl : './cuestionario.component.html',
               styleUrls   : [ './cuestionario.component.scss' ],
             } )
export class CuestionarioComponent implements OnInit {
  forma : FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public fb : FormBuilder,
  ) {

    this.forma = this.fb.group (
      {
        preg1      : [ null ],
        preg2      : [ null ],
        preg3      : [ null ],
        preg4      : [ null ],
      },
    );
}
}
```

**HTML Padre**

```
<form [formGroup]="forma" novalidate>
      <app-pregunta
        [listaPreguntas]="listaPreguntas"
        formControlName="preg2"
        name="preg2"
      ></app-pregunta>
</form>
```

**Componente Hijo**

```
@Component ( {
               selector    : 'app-pregunta',
               templateUrl : './pregunta.component.html',
               styleUrls   : [ './pregunta.component.scss' ],
             } )
export class PreguntaComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input () listaPreguntas : any[];
  @Input () control : FormControl;
  @Input () noPregunta : any;
  @Input () group : FormGroup;
  listaOpciones : any = [
     { nombre : 'Opción 1', value : 1, titulo : 'NO sirve para nada' },
     { nombre : 'Opción 2', value : 2, titulo : 'Me sirve un poco.' },
     { nombre : 'Opción 3', value : 3, titulo : 'Me sirve mucho' },
     { nombre : 'Opción 4', value : 4, titulo : 'Me sirve totalmente.' },
  ];

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**HTML Hijo**

```
<div [formGroup]="group" class="container mt-4">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <mat-radio-group
        class="mt-5"
        required>
        <mat-radio-button
          *ngFor="let opcion of listaOpciones"
          [matTooltip]="opcion.titulo"
          [value]="opcion.value"
          class="ml-4"
          matTooltipClass="tooltip-red"
          matTooltipPosition="below">
          {{ opcion.nombre }}
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group> 
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Revisa este [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766308/how-to-bind-default-value-in-mat-radio-group-angular-reactive-forms), tal vez sea tu solución

Comment: Creo que de pronto no has entendido que es lo que necesito, necesito anidar  un componente hijo dentro de un padre pasándole un formControlName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

justamente acabo de implementar esto hace un día y me encontraba en exactamente la misma situación. Te dejaré un ejemplo muy sencillo y ya me dices si necesitas uno exactamente con tu código.

Con esta implementación ya después podrás acceder a sus valores mediante la propiedad del padre que tiene el formulario. Así:

`this.formulario.get('correo').value`

### Componente Padre

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-componente-padre',
    templateUrl: './app-componente-padre.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-componente-padre.component.css']
})
export class ComponentePadreComponent implements OnInit {
    // Propiedad del padre
    formulario: FormGroup;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.formulario = new FormGroup({
          correo:       new FormControl('', Validators.required),
       });
    }

}
```

### HTML del Padre

```html
<form [formGroup]="formulario">

  <!-- Label es la propiedad @Input dentro del componente hijo, igual que el formulario y ese viene de la propiedad del padre. -->
  <app-componente-hijo [formulario]="formulario" label="correo"></app-componente-hijo>

</form>
```

### Componente Hijo

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-componente-hijo',
    templateUrl: './app-componente-hijo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-componente-hijo.component.css']
})
export class ComponenteHijoComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() formulario: FormGroup;
    @Input() label: string;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

### HTML del Hijo

```html
<!-- Esto lo maneja Angular. 'formulario' es el @Input -->
<div [formGroup]="formulario">
  <!-- Lo mismo con 'label' -->
  <select [formControlName]="label">
    <option value="">Seleccionar correo...</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: mil gracias, era lo que buscaa

Comment: @Gdaimon No hay de qué. Si te sirvió, márcala como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

creo que lo estas viendo al revés, el hijo no tiene que contener la lista de preguntas ya que se lo estas pasando como `input` desde el padre. Creo que el problema es que aún no queda claro como funcionan los 'formularios reactivos'

Comment: realmente los hijos siempre van a tener las mismas opciones, lo que va a cambiar son las preguntas, pero necesito que cada componente tenga su propio formControlName y que emita su valor al padre